# <base href=""> breaks the layout

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a web page. The introduction of a simple `<base href="">` tag in the head of the page creates lots of unexpected problems such as dismantlement of the layout of the page, size of figures etc. Here is the web page without  http://vlab.mooo.info/tanks and this is with the  tag: http://vlab.mooo.info/tanks/wrong.php.

Note: I've tested with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: `<base>` usually applies to all hyperlinks and references, including stylesheets and scripts.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that one should change all relative URLs just because a base tag was introduced?

Comment: No, one shouldn't use `<base>`. :)

Comment: @Quentin: It's just good to know how everything works to have there in case you really need it. `<base>` simplifies coding in some cases - see http://tinyurl.com/co9x9mu

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis — The author of that article thinks that W3Schools and the W3C are the same organisation. I've never seen a case when `<base>` was a better solution to a problem then a template variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have file 
`http://vlab.mooo.info/tanks/style-tanks.css` 
which is called in 
`http://vlab.mooo.info/tanks/` 
via 
`<link href="style-tanks.css" />`

With base href set to the root, the browser looks for `http://vlab.mooo.info/style-tanks.css` which is wrong

Change to
`<link href="/tanks/style-tanks.css" />`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is line #14:

You have

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style-tanks.css" >`

Should be:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./tanks/style-tanks.css" >`